# How can user make input type date empty?

Tags: html, date, input

I wish to use the new input attribute from HTML5 DATE, only one problem, in the logic of the project, the user must be have the choice to delete the value, but i don't see, how to set empty value on this inputs

Comment: What platform? I can delete the value on iOS Safari, Android Chrome, and desktop Chrome.

Comment: In UI? Can you make screenshot and show me, where the button is?

Comment: Do you want to show `mm/dd/yyyy` or just make the field blank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to make the value shown to `dd/mm/yyyy`, then click on `Clear` button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, in my Opera on Linux i have it not, but good that the first one Browser is on the right way

Comment: Very old answer. Much has changed.

Answer (score 5):

In HTML5 on Chrome the date picker popup has a "clear" button at the bottom (next to "today")

```
<input type="date" value="">
```

Answer (score -1):

`<input type="date" name="NameItAnythingYouWant" value="">`