# How do you programmatically clear HTML5 date fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I'm looking for a way to programmatically clear HTML5 date fields with Javascript (specifically jQuery). So far I have tried two methods which I thought obvious:

```
$('input[type=date]').val('');

$('input[type=date]').val('0000-00-00');
```

But neither of them work on the latest version of Chrome for PCs at least, haven't tried them with other browsers or platforms yet. Is there an API call or something that can clear date fields in a cross-browser way? Solutions I have searched for like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535475/how-can-user-make-input-type-date-empty) require the user to clear the date field whereas I need this to be done programmatically.

Comment: Doesn't it have a value by default? (So you can't change it?)

Comment: @putvande No, a plain input[type=date] field will have a default 'dd/mm/yyyy' placeholder value on my system if no value is specified.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. That is `empty` I guess. You want it to have no value at all?

Comment: @putvande I want to empty it, yes. 'dd/mm/yyyy' is not a value since it won't be detected if you probe its value with Javascript, it will just be blank.

Comment: Does it need to be empty or can it just *seem* empty?

Comment: @oGeez The field will be saved to a database so I can't have it appear to empty but actually still contain the original value when the form is saved

Answer (score 17):

`$("input[type=date]").val("")` works for me in chrome. It sets the input field to dd/mm/yyyy.

Maybe it's browser specific. Most browsers have only partial or no support for this input: http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m which is the latest release according to the updater and that doesn't work for me. My big problem is I need it to work on at least iOS Safari too so I can't release something that only works in Chrome.

Comment: i have exactly the same version on ubuntu/linux. tried it on this site http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html by entering ```$("input[type=date]").val("")``` into the console.

Comment: Interesting. When I altered the .change() selector from all date inputs to a single date field specified by ID and tried $(this).val('') it doesn't work, but if I use $('#ID_HERE').val('') this works. Thanks! Difficult to apply to a general function though.

Comment: Does not work as of current Chrome version.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to do it recently and i've made this little hack... Seems to do the job.

It was just with JavaScript, but the jQuery version is pretty the same...

```js
function reset_date_native() {
  var date_input = document.getElementById('date-id');

  //erase the input value
  date_input.value = '';

  //prevent error on older browsers (aka IE8)
  if (date_input.type === 'date') {
    //update the input content (visually)
    date_input.type = 'text';
    date_input.type = 'date';
  }
}

function reset_date_jquery() {
  $('#date-id').val('')
    .attr('type', 'text')
    .attr('type', 'date');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date-id" type="date" />
<button onclick="reset_date_native()">Trigger the reset function (native)</button>
<button onclick="reset_date_jquery()">Trigger the reset function (jQuery)</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you can't clear a date field, this could also depend on a browser bug.
I spend some time until I found out that you cannot reset the date in Firefox if the date control is disabled.
See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1465979

Without the bug, I am able to clear the date like that:

```
document.getElementById("myDate").value = "";
```

Comment: I had a similar experience with FireFox (version 75).  The date "text" for a readonly type=date input field would not clear even though the actual value was changed to "" by JavaScript.  In Chrome and IE 11, the field text did clear in addition to the underlying value. I worked around it by changing the readonly attribute to false before changing the value, then changing the reaonly attribute back to true after clearing the date value.  Now it works in FF, Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("datePicker").valueAsDate = null;
```

this line of code works with my browser (chrome) , didn't tested in other browsers

Answer (score 3):

You can change the date as empty

```
$('#invoiceDate').val(new Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

Set myDate = one space.
I like simple solutions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the placeholder;

```
$('input[type=date]')[0].valueAsDate = '';
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

this line works with my browser (chrome, latest version)

```
$('input[type=date]')[0].value = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the reset function of your form ?
You can do this with reset button :

```
      <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

or programmaticaly :

```
      $("#yourFormId").reset();
```

or

```
      $('input[type=date]').reset();
```

Comment: There is no jQuery `reset()` method

Comment: so this one  
`$('#testForm').trigger("reset");`

Comment: For some bizarre reason, the method is: `$('#configform')[0].reset();` Do not ask why an ID selector returns an indexed array of forms. Anyway, none of these methods actually clear **date** inputs in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the native `defaultValue` property:

```
$('input[type=date]').each( function resetDate(){
  this.value = this.defaultValue;
} );
```

This works as long as the form doesn't have an initial `value` specified, [as demonstrated in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CDDbD/).

Answer (score 0):

This solution checks if a default value exists and, if so, uses it to reset the input. Otherwise, it clears the input it by updating value and valueAsDate.

Info on valueAsDate available at: [w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/common-input-element-attributes.html).

```
var dateEl = element.find('input#myDateInput[type="date"]');
dateEl[0].value = ('undefined' !== typeof dateEl[0].defaultValue) ? dateEl[0].defaultValue : '';
if (dateEl[0].value !== '') {
    dateEl[0].valueAsDate = new Date(dateEl[0].value);
} else {
    dateEl[0].valueAsDate = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the value.
I wanted the onchange() function to run when I set the value to empty. Normally, this always works but for date it didn't even if the value appeared to be blanked and you blurred the input

I discovered that I had to force the onchange() function to trigger the value change too.

```
document.getElementById('mydate').value='';
document.getElementById('mydate').onchange();
```

It worked for me and now my form fades out when the value is blanked.
I do not know why that works. I tried blur() and focus() but nothing else seems to work.