# JavaScript suppress date format warning

Tags: javascript, web, warnings, suppress-warnings

Whenever I try to reset a date input using JavaScript, like so:

```
//input_id is an id of a date input
document.getElementById(input_id).value = "0000-00-00";
```

I get a warning in the console:

```
The specified value "0000-00-00" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

Does anyone know a way to suppress this warning so it won't show? The JS keeps on running smoothly but I want to get rid of these warnings.

If you have another way of resetting a date input (without raising a warning) I will be happy to hear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, its same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885890/how-do-you-programmatically-clear-html5-date-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the warning because years, months, and days start at 1, not 0. 0 is an invalid value for all of them. But there's a simpler way to reset an input element..

You can just set the value to the empty string which is the initial default value.

```
var di = document.createElement("input");
di.type = "date";
console.log(di.value); // outputs ""
document.body.appendChild(di);

// change the value if you want

// to reset:
di.value = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a empty string value

```
document.getElementById(input_id).value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your Javascript call

```
console.clear();
```

This clears all warnings and errors from your console.

You can also replace `console.warn` with your own code like:

`console.warn = function () { };`.

NOT recommended because you will not get any warnings to your console this way.