# Removing the selected date from an input element that has the type "date"

Tags: html

In Chrome, when you use an input element with the type set to "date":

```
<input type="date" />
```

Chrome displays an arrow that you can click on to select a date. In my web app though, if the user decides to remove the date, there does not appear to be any way of doing this. How can I allow the user to remove the selected date so that no date is shown in the input element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885890/how-do-you-programmatically-clear-html5-date-fields

Comment: My guess is that you are at the whim of how each particular browser would implement this.  You might have to use a custom widget, e.g. something from Query or Angular, to get the behavior you want.

Comment: It's only for Chrome. And it cannot be done programmatically. The user must be able to clear the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery datePicker

```
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
});
```

or

```
$('selector').datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but was hoping to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: I doubt if we can achieve this only using HTML5. Might need javascript or JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You could display a different type of input for mobile users using a prompt text, then validate it on form submit. Support for input type `date` is still patchy across different browsers.