# HTML Displays on HTML Form Submit & Form does not refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I had an issue where my code was being displayed to the user, this was resolved by changing the `alert(this.response);` ajax code to display a custom message.

I also had an issue where my form was not refreshing after submission.
This was resolved by manually clearing each field in the `"onreadystatechange"` function.

> I encountered this error and found this on another post(Mozilla bug
>   that doesn't clear date fields):
>   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1465979
>
> [How do you programmatically clear HTML5 date fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885890/how-do-you-programmatically-clear-html5-date-fields)
>
> I had to switch to chrome for this as firefox does not clear the field... Any other code that clears date fields in firefox?

Please see below code snippets:

**Code to create xml document**

```
    <script>

  var template = [
              '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
              '<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">',
              '<Data>',
              ' <SubmitBy><?SubmitBy?></SubmitBy>',
              ' <Level1><?Level1?></Level1>',
              ' <Level2><?Level2?></Level2>',
              ' <Level3><?Level3?></Level3>',
              ' <Level4><?Level4?></Level4>',
              ' <Title><?Title?></Title>',
              ' <Subject><?Subject?></Subject>',
              ' <Author><?Author?></Author>',
              ' <Keywords1><?Keywords1?></Keywords1>',
              ' <Keywords2><?Keywords2?></Keywords2>',
              ' <Destroy_Date><?Destroy_Date?></Destroy_Date>',
              ' <Projects><?Projects?></Projects>',
              '</Data>',
              '</unattend>'
            ].join('\r\n');


            const ajax=function( params ){
                with( new XMLHttpRequest() ){
                    onreadystatechange=function(e){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 ){
                           alert("Your form was successfully saved"); 
                           document.getElementById("Level1").innerHTML = '<option selected="selected"> - Select 1 - </option><option value="FINANCE">FINANCE</option><option value="JOB OBSERVATIONS">JOB OBSERVATIONS</option><option value="MARKETING">MARKETING</option><option value="PAYROLL">PAYROLL</option><option value="PROJECTS">PROJECTS</option>';
                           document.getElementById("Level2").innerHTML = '';
                           document.getElementById("Level3").innerHTML = '';
                           document.getElementById("Level4").innerHTML = '';
                           document.getElementById("Title").value = '';
                           document.getElementById("Subject").value = '';
                           document.getElementById("Author").value = '';
                           document.getElementById("Keywords1").value = '';
                           document.getElementById("Keywords2").value = '';
                           document.getElementById("Date").value = 'yyyy/mm/dd';
                           document.getElementById("Destroy_Date").value = 'yyyy/mm/dd';
                        }
                    }
                    open( 'POST', location.href, true );
                    setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    send( params );
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
                document.querySelector('input[ type="button" ]').addEventListener('click', e=>{
                    let vars={};                    
                    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('form > input[ type="text" ]') ).forEach( field =>{
                     vars[ field.name ]=field.value
                      });
                       Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('select') ).forEach( field =>{
                     vars[ field.name ]=field.value
                      });
                      Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('form > input[ type="date" ]') ).forEach( field =>{
                     vars[ field.name ]=field.value
                      });
                    let xml=template.replace(/<\?(\w+)\?>/ig, (match,name)=>{
                        return vars[name];
                    });
                    ajax.call( this, 'xml='+xml);           
                    })
                });

</script>
```

**PHP Code Behind**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['xml'] ) ){
    $Counter = date("Y-m-d") . ' ' . Time();
        $file  = 'D:\\Input\\' . $Counter . ' - Export.xml';
        $bytes = file_put_contents( $file, $_POST['xml'] );
        exit( sprintf('%d bytes written to %s',$bytes,realpath($file) ) );
    }
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form method='POST'>
    <label>Submitted By:</label>
    <input type="text" id="SubmitBy" name="SubmitBy"></input>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="TableSpacing">
        <h2 style="padding-left: 20px;">User Selection</h2>
    <table id="table" style="padding-left:20px;">
      <tr>
        <td width="200px">Select Level 1 of 4</td>
        <td>
            <form method='POST'>
                <select id="Level1" name="Level1" style="width:200px;" onchange="FunctionLevel1()">
                    <option selected="selected"> - Select 1 - </option>
                    <option value="FINANCE">FINANCE</option>
                    <option value="JOB OBSERVATIONS">JOB OBSERVATIONS</option>
                    <option value="MARKETING">MARKETING</option>
                    <option value="PAYROLL">PAYROLL</option>
                    <option value="PROJECTS">PROJECTS</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200px">Select Level 2 of 4</td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST">
                <select id="Level2" name="Level2" style="width:200px;" onchange="FunctionLevel2()">
                </select>
            </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200px">Select Level 3 of 4</td>
        <td>
            <form method='POST'>
                <select id="Level3" name="Level3" style="width:200px;" onchange="FunctionLevel3()">
                </select>
            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="200px">Select Level 4 of 4</td>
        <td>
        <form method='POST'>
        <select id="Level4" name="Level4" style="width:200px;">
          </select>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="TableSpacing2">
    <table style="padding-left:20px;">
    <tr>
    <td width="200px">Title</td>
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input type="text" style="width: 195px;" id="Title" name="Title"></input>   
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="200px">Subject</td>
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input type="text" style="width: 195px;" id="Subject" name="Subject"></input>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="200px">Author</td>
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input type="text" style="width: 195px;" id="Author" name="Author"></input>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="200px">Keywords1</td>
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input type="text" style="width: 195px;" id="Keywords1" name="Keywords1"></input>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="200px">Keywords2</td>
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input type="text" style="width: 195px;" id="Keywords2" name="Keywords2"></input>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="200px">Date</td>
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input type="date" style="width: 195px;" id="Date" name="Date" onchange="Destroy_Date()"></input>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="200px">Destroy Date</td>
    <td>
    <form method='POST'>
    <input readonly="readonly" type="date" style="width: 195px;" id="Destroy_Date" name="Destroy_Date"></input>
    </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Projects">
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Save Info" style="margin-top: 10px;width: 100%;height: 30px;background-color: #444;color: white;font-family: cinzel;font-size: 16pt;border: 2px solid gray;"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you are not actually submitting a form, but only send the data in the background using AJAX - then it is your responsibility to update the document afterwards. You’d need to hide the form, resp. remove/replace it with your success message. (But please don’t reflexively ask _how_ immediately now, but go _research_ this, if it doesn’t mean anything to you yet.)

Comment: Hi @Misorude Thanks for the information. I'll have a look into hiding/clearing the form per submission. Could you possibly give me an indication of when/where in the code the popup is displayed with all of the html code and the prompt to click OK? I have been trying to hide this for a couple of hours now..

Comment: What popup? I don’t see anything in the code you have shown that would open a popup.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the popup that I receive when submitting the form.
I'm also not sure where it is generated and why it is displayed, hope someone can help with this.

Comment: Ah, not a popup, an alert actually … well that comes from `alert( this.response )` of course. (The response to your AJAX request appears to be a full HTML document again - whether that makes sense, or it should be something else altogether to begin with - depends, on what you actually want to achieve, resp. do with that response.)

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I don't see any.

Comment: Thanks @misorude - Solved my issue.

Comment: I'll update the post in just a second with the updated code