# How to reset input date value when the form is prefilled

Tags: html, jquery, dom, input

I have already checked this: [How do you programmatically clear HTML5 date fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885890/how-do-you-programmatically-clear-html5-date-fields/20886080)

In my case, my form is pre-filled by existing value, and I want user change the date by null in database via the form updatting.
Here are what I tried:

```
$('input[name=theDate]').val('');    //does not work.

$('input[name=theDate]').removeAttr('value'); //does not work too
```

In the first case I get jj/mm/aaaa in the input but in dom I always have the existing value for this input

```
<input type="date" name="theDate" value="2022-04-03">
```

In the second case, I get jj/mm/aaaa and attribute value does not exist anymore, but the server is getting the existing value like the attribute exists but is just hide.

```
<input type="date" name="theDate">
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: Your original attempt of `$('input[name=theDate]').val('');` works. Are you sure you're putting it in `$(document).ready()`? Are you saying that you want to also clear the input mask?

Comment: How are you sending your form?

Comment: The thig is I do not want to put it on page loading. I try it after click on a link "Reset. I am sending the form with php, no ajax, only pure php, I am using laravel

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the "id" attribute?

```
<input type="date" name="theDate" id="theDate" value="2022-04-03">
```

```
$("#theDate").val("");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer does not answer his question as the selector he's using clearly already works.