# Reset date input fields when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a question how to reset date input fields when a specific radio button is selected. Currently I use a Javascript to reset two radio buttons when the radio button "inactive" is selected. This is working. But I'm not able to get this to work as well for the date input fields values.

**Goal:** When radio button "vacation-inactive" is selected reset all radio buttons AND all date input values.

What is the best approach to get this to work? Thanks

```js
    document.getElementById('vacation-inactive').addEventListener('click', function () {
      ["vacation-immediately", "vacation-planned"].forEach(function(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).checked = false;
      });
      return false;
    })
```

```css
/* Vacation input fields */
/* Hide & Show */
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px; /* little bit of a magic number :( */
  overflow: visible;
}

.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  input[type="radio"]:checked ~ &,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ & {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

  /* Radio buttons */
.wrapper{
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  /* box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
}
.wrapper .option{
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper .option .dot{
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .option .dot::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #0069d9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;
}

/* Vacation activ OR inactive */
#vacation-inactive:checked:checked ~ .vacation-inactive,
#vacation-active:checked:checked ~ .vacation-active{
  border-color: #0069d9;
  background: #0069d9;
}
#vacation-inactive:checked:checked ~ .vacation-inactive .dot,
#vacation-active:checked:checked ~ .vacation-active .dot{
  background: #fff;
}
#vacation-inactive:checked:checked ~ .vacation-inactive .dot::before,
#vacation-active:checked:checked ~ .vacation-active .dot::before{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.wrapper .option span{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #808080;
}
#vacation-inactive:checked:checked ~ .vacation-inactive span,
#vacation-active:checked:checked ~ .vacation-active span{
  color: #fff;
}



/* Vacation Mode */
#vacation-immediately:checked:checked ~ .vacation-immediately,
#vacation-planned:checked:checked ~ .vacation-planned{
  border-color: #0069d9;
  background: #0069d9;
}
#vacation-immediately:checked:checked ~ .vacation-immediately .dot,
#vacation-planned:checked:checked ~ .vacation-planned .dot{
  background: #fff;
}
#vacation-immediately:checked:checked ~ .vacation-immediately .dot::before,
#vacation-planned:checked:checked ~ .vacation-planned .dot::before{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.wrapper .option span{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #808080;
}
#vacation-immediately:checked:checked ~ .vacation-immediately span,
#vacation-planned:checked:checked ~ .vacation-planned span{
  color: #fff;
}


/* Vacation date picker */
[type="date"] {
  background:#fff url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/calendar_2.png)  97% 50% no-repeat ;
}
[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}

input#vacation_date {
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: 190px;
}

label#vacation_date {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Start Vacation?</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="radio" name="SelectVacationMode" id="vacation-inactive" value="vacation_inactive" checked>
   <label for="vacation-inactive" class="option vacation-inactive">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <span>Inaktiv</span>
   </label>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="SelectVacationMode" id="vacation-active" value="vacation_active">
      <label for="vacation-active" class="option vacation-active">
         <div class="dot"></div>
         <span>Aktiv</span>
      </label>
      <div class="reveal-if-active">
         <input type="radio" name="SelectVacationType" id="vacation-immediately" value="immediately_vacation">
         <label for="vacation-immediately" class="option vacation-immediately">
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <span>Sofort</span>
         </label>
         <div>
            <input type="radio" name="SelectVacationType" id="vacation-planned" value="date_vacation">
            <label for="vacation-planned" class="option vacation-planned">
               <div class="dot"></div>
               <span>Planen</span>
            </label>
            <div class="reveal-if-active">
               <label id="vacation_date" for="start">Start date</label>
               <input type="date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" id="vacation_date" name="vacation-start" required>
               <label id="vacation_date" for="end">End date</label>
               <input type="date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" id="vacation_date" name="vacation-end" required>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all you need to fix your faulty HTML - IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. And you should probably go read up on how the `for` attribute on a label element works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53334531/16272400), I would give an id to each input fields, for example for the first one :

```
<input id="myDate" type="date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" id="vacation_date" name="vacation-start" required>
```

And then try this command in the console after you give a value to your input, it will clear the value.

```
document.getElementById("myDate").value = "";
```